# Issue in passing parameter in oracle Pl-Sql function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I’m write one function `funGetAccount’ in`Oracle Pl-Sql` passing parameter ProdCd but query has consider its  statement how it solved I’m not understand my req is same query pls don’t change the query design.

```
Function  funGetAccount (ProdCd in Number)
          Return Varchar2 Is
          varResult       Varchar2(2000);

          Begin

          varResult :=  ' Select AC_NO, NAME From ('
                     || ' Select AC_NO, NAME'
                     || ' From Tab1 Where PRODUCT_CD = ProdCd)';


         varResult := varResult;
         Return varResult;
End funGetAccount;
```

Comment: Do you want to return `AC_NO` and `NAME` returned from query?

Comment: Yes now fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function  funGetAccount (ProdCd in Number)
          Return Varchar2 Is
          varResult       Varchar2(2000);

          Begin

          varResult :=  ' Select AC_NO, NAME From ('
                     || ' Select AC_NO, NAME'
                     || ' From Tab1 Where PRODUCT_CD = '''|| ProdCd ||''')';


         varResult := varResult;
         Return varResult;
End funGetAccount;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return `AC_NO` and `NAME` concatenated by space. You cannot return 2 values from it.

Also make sure that your query is returning only 1 row for the given `prodcd` else it return only first row.

```
create or replace function funGetAccount (ProdCd in Number)
          Return Varchar2 Is
          varResult Varchar2(2000);
          Begin
  Select AC_NO||' '||NAME 
             into varResult
             From Tab1 Where PRODUCT_CD = ProdCd and rownum <2;
       Return varResult;
End funGetAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what definitely you want to archive with this function: return select statement or retrieve data.

In the first case you should do:

```
Function  funGetAccount (ProdCd in Number)
Return Varchar2 
Is
    varResult       Varchar2(2000);
Begin
     varResult :=  ' Select AC_NO, NAME From ('
                   || ' Select AC_NO, NAME'
                   || ' From Tab1 ' 
                   || ' Where PRODUCT_CD = ' || ProdCd || ')';

    Return varResult;
End funGetAccount;
```

In the second (retrieve data)

```
create or replace function funGetAccount (ProdCd in Number)
Return Varchar2 
Is
    varResult Varchar2(2000);
Begin
    Select AC_NO||' '||NAME 
    into varResult
    From Tab1 
    Where PRODUCT_CD = ProdCd;

    Return varResult;

End funGetAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the question i can see there are two requirements which can come into picture.

1) OP wants to return the raw SQL statement through FUNCTION.

2) OP wants SQL output in CONCATENATED WAY.

I have focused on 2 point where i have incorporated some of the good coding practices like EXCEPTION Handling. Hope it helps.

```
FUNCTION funGetAccount(
    ProdCd IN NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  p_result_out VARCHAR2(100);
  varResult    VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  varResult := 'Select AC_NO||'',''||NAME From                 
              ( Select AC_NO, NAME  From Tab1 Where PRODUCT_CD = '''||ProdCd||''')';
  BEGIN --> Exception handling missed
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varResult INTO p_result_out;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN --> Others is broad term you can catch specific exceptions like no data found too many rows etc
    NULL;          -- Your action logic
  END;
  RETURN p_result_out;
END funGetAccount;
```